# Apache default port change not working ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, port

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

I tried to change my default apache2 port from 80 to 8085
I edited `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

I edited line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8085`

then restarted my apache service
then to test this in browser I putted `http://localhost:8085`
The result is `404 Not Found`

then I opened terminal and ran

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8085
```

o/p is:

```
tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:8085       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN
```

Am I doing something wrong? or Am I missing something?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would almost have to guess, given your configuration is correct, that you needed to just to reload and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 reload

sudo service apache2 restart
```

If not, I believe why this has gone unanswered is there was not enough basic info posting like "/var/log/apache2/error.info" output or further explanation, along with providing us with what you had done prior as far as configuration.

Hope you got it handled and did not give up!

=^)

Comment: This is a valid problem, and I faced it just now. You also need to change the port in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default from 80 to 8085

Comment: THanks gt5050, i did everything except 000-default and didnt work, read your comment, changed file and now its fully working, like a charm. Thanks!